# Vscode tooltips colors syntax of rendering documentation instead of the monotonous white syntactic

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm looking for a Vscode extension that can add better colors syntax for rendering documentation instead of the monotonous white syntactic !
Has anyone already found this and could share a link with me?

Actually on my side the documentation render in full white !
Am look for something like seconde frame ! [Photoshoped]

Usually its for javascript code but also typescript, where both handle documentation rendering.
[image]

i also open issue here in case
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140872

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you tried Prettier? Idk if it works for documentation but it's pretty good for general syntax highlighting.

Comment: these tooltips are rendered Markup containing color codes. thus the extension generating the text should modify the text, you can create an issue, maybe if there is a syntax definition for such text you could mark this block with the languageId

Comment: @ChristianOCon good to know you don't get the same brightness!, my monitor is a TV, where it's super bright for me, but I know some people don't get the same print screen because driver handled by nvidia on my side!
But no Prettier dont rendering documentation for the vscode tooltips.

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for this info, I've never created a vscode extension, and i have not really the time get interested , I'm looking more for a ready-made solution!

Comment: you don't need to create an extension, you have to ask the developer what has written the extension that shows the tooltip.

Comment: @rioV8 as a said , this is photoshop made by myself !

Comment: from as hawser get from Github by a vscode dev, it seem not possible with current API extention of vscode ! 